# How to send Custom Error from Lambda to Api Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I try to send custom error from lambda to API gateway. I am getting an error at the API gateway level.

> Authorizer result body before parsing: {"messageString":"Missing Authentication Token","responseType":"ACCESS_DENIED","statusCode":"403"}
>   Mon Dec 30 10:42:51 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid JSON in response: Unrecognized field "messageString" , not marked as ignorable
>   Mon Dec 30 10:42:51 UTC 2019 : AuthorizerConfigurationException

I have already updated the API gateway response as per the aws docs. [api gateway responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-response-using-the-console.html)

Below template added into the 403 gateway responses.

```
{
 "message":"$context.error.messageString",
 "type": "$context.error.responseType",
 "statusCode": "'403'",
 "stage": "$context.stage",
 "resourcePath": "$context.resourcePath",
 "stageVariables.a": "$stageVariables.a"
}
```

**lambda Fn code**

```
 const response = {
  "messageString": "Access Denied",
  "responseType": "ACCESS_DENIED",
  "statusCode": '403',
};
context.done(null, response);
```

**Also tried to send same data with but getting the same error.**

```
  const response = {
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "response": "ACCESS_DENIED",
  "statusCode": '403',
};
context.done(null, response);
```

Comment: is it  because your template says `$context.error.messageString` while the response doesn't have `error.messageString`?

Comment: Thanks @AshishModi for reply. When I try to wrap response into "error". It shows  Unrecognized field "error" , not marked as ignorable